# How to get last inserted row ID from WordPress database?

Tags: wordpress, auto-increment, race-condition

My WordPress plugin has a table with a **AUTO_INCREMENT** primary key field called ID. When a new row is inserted into the table, I'd like to get the ID value of the insertion.

The feature is to using AJAX to post data to server to insert into DB. The new row ID is returned in the AJAX response to update client status. It is possible that multiple clients are posting data to server at the same time. So, I have to make sure that each AJAX request get the EXACT new row ID in response.

In PHP, there is a method called ***mysql_insert_id*** for this feature.But, it is valid for race condition only if the argument is ***link_identifier*** of last operation. My operation with database is on $wpdb. How to extract the ***link_identifier*** from $wpdb to make sure mysql_insert_id work? Is there any other way to get the last-inserted-row id from $wpdb?

Thanks.

Comment: The link|resource is stored in `$wpdb->dbh`, but it is defined as `protected $dbh;` ...sou you can't access it directly, therefore, use answer below :)

Answer (score 252, accepted):

Straight after the `$wpdb->insert()` that does the insert, do this:

```
$lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;
```

More information about how to do things the WordPress way can be found in the WordPress codex. The details above were found here on the [wpdb class page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#Class_Variables)

Comment: Is it like this:    `$lastid = $wpdb->$insert_id`       ?

Comment: "This function returns false if the row could not be inserted. Otherwise, it returns the number of affected rows (which will always be 1)."  From: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#INSERT_rows

Comment: @unbreak - wrong function there ... you're reading about wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );

Comment: It is also useful to know that if you use $wpdb->query, it will still assign insert_id.

Comment: was not necessary, but I think it improves a bit, statement highlighted, and removed indentation as it's not required for single line.

Comment: Is this using  `LAST_INSERT_ID()` specifically in the sense it functions in the ways described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html)?

Comment: What if client B does $wpdb->insert() in between client's A $wpdb->insert() and $wpdb->$insert_id? In that case client A will get B's id. Can that happen?

Comment: @blaze9 it shouldn't, because the wpdb class should be mitigating that race condition for you, if you absolutely have to get that ID back and are experiencing these race conditions, you could then use the params you used in the insert to select the row back out and get the ID that way

Comment: It's probably best to check if `$wpdb->insert()` is not `false` before checking `$wpdb->insert_id`.

Answer (score 19):

This is how I did it, in my code

```
 ...
 global $wpdb;
 $query =  "INSERT INTO... VALUES(...)" ;
 $wpdb->query(
        $wpdb->prepare($query)
);
return $wpdb->insert_id;
...
```

[More Class Variables](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#Class_Variables)

Comment: "This function returns false if the row could not be inserted. Otherwise, it returns the number of affected rows (which will always be 1)." from: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#INSERT_rows

Comment: It works. The `$wpdb->query` returns the len of affected rows and `$wpdb->insert_id` has the last inserted id. Thanks!

Comment: This is better for me, because I want to capture inserts that will otherwise return an error due to duplicate column values on a unique column.  There is no way to `INSERT IGNORE` with `$wpdb->insert` unfortunately.

Comment: @unbreak - Looks like it's returning the `insert_id` to me, not the number of affected rows.

Comment: @unbreak This sentence is relating to the insert() method as opposed to the insert_id property. The way the docs are structured does make this unclear though.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to get the last id way after inserting it, so

```
$lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;
```

Was not an option.

Did the follow:

```
global $wpdb;
$id = $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT id FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'table' . ' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');
```

Comment: This is risky because someone else may have inserted something since.

Answer (score 2):

Get the last inserted row id in WP like this.

```
global $wpdb;
$order = ['product_name'=>'Computer', 'os_system'=>'Linux'];
$wpdb->insert('wp_product_orders', $order );
$last_inserted_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it too :

```
$last = $wpdb->get_row("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table_name'");
$lastid = $last->Auto_increment;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause a problem if two records were inserted at almost the exact same time by two different processes? Both processes could insert at the same time (or close enough to the same time) so that the auto_increment would return the same number for both processes.

Answer (score -1):

just like this :

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name='lorem_ipsum';
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");
print_r($results[0]->id);
```

simply your selecting all the rows then order them DESC by id , and displaying only the first

Comment: This is risky because someone else may have inserted something since.

Answer (score -7):

Putting the call to `mysql_insert_id()` inside a transaction, should do it:

```
mysql_query('BEGIN');
// Whatever code that does the insert here.
$id = mysql_insert_id();
mysql_query('COMMIT');
// Stuff with $id.
```

Comment: That's not doing it using the $wpdb object as was mentioned in the OP.